# Loop Through Checkboxes to addEventListener to each box

Tags: javascript, checkbox, addeventlistener

I am trying to add an event listener to each checkbox as an alternative to the onclick method.  The code I am working with is simple.

The code can be seen here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Buleria28/5a6zL013/

or here Javascript:

```
function letter() {
 document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "ABCD";
 }

var box = document.getElementsByName("test");
if (box[0].addEventListener) {
for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
   box[i].addEventListener("change", letter, false);
 }
} else if (box[0].attachEvent) {
 for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
   box[i].attachEvent("onchange", letter);
 }
```

The HTML is:

```
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="A">A</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="B">B</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="C">C</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="D">D</label>
</div>
```

Comment: One reason your code might not be working in `jsfiddle` is because you're missing a trailing `}`

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @mjkaufer in the comments above, your original example works fine after you add the closing curly brace `}`.

However, there is a simpler way to loop over the checkboxes. Try using `forEach` to iterate over each element returned by `document.getElementsByName("test")`:

```
function letter(){
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "ABCD";
}

document.getElementsByName("test").forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener("change", letter, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("onchange", letter);
    }
});
```

Comment: The existing code seems to work. There's just a missing curly brace.

Comment: Very true -- I'm just providing a simpler and cleaner example of iterating over a set of returned elements.